# How to set position of cursor in UITextField Xcode in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

I have a little problem, i'd like to move the cursor to the right in a UITextField in Xcode in Swift. 
By default, it is completely on the left and it is not very nice.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to set the cursor to the right, or be able to write in the text field from right to left?

Comment: i want to shift the cursor a little on the right because for the moment the cursor is at the beginning of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following solutions ?

Controlling cursor position in a UITextField is complicated because so many abstractions are involved with input boxes and calculating positions. However, it's certainly possible. You can use the member function

```
setSelectedTextRange:
```

Here's a function which takes a range and selects the texts in that range. If you just want to place the cursor at a certain index, just use a range with length 0:

```
+ (void)selectTextForInput:(UITextField *)input atRange:(NSRange)range {
    UITextPosition *start = [input positionFromPosition:[input beginningOfDocument] 
                                                 offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [input positionFromPosition:start
                                               offset:range.length];
    [input setSelectedTextRange:[input textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end]];
}
```

For example, to place the cursor at idx in the UITextField input:

```
[Helpers selectTextForInput:input 
                        atRange:NSMakeRange(idx, 0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func setCursor() {
    let paddingView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 44))
    textfield1.leftView = paddingView;
    texfield1.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    textfield1.placeholder = "Full Name"
}
```

You can adjust the position of padding view(x,y,width,height) the way you want.